# Getting started with Azure Repos: How do I upload files?

Tags: azure-devops

I am developing a game, and am looking for a way to manage version control between two computers. I was directed to use Repos.
I'm new to using version control at all, and when I try to follow tutorials for DevOps it talks about team coordination stuff that is NOT what I'm looking for. Honestly I'm not sure if this is the right solution for me.

I'm really trying to share files between two computers. Not just code, but also textures, meshes, level data, sounds, and ultimately the entire project. (And have a system to push/pull this data between computers, of course.)
I made a project within DevOps, but when I go to "Files" in Repos, I only have options to connect to a Git. How can I select files I need to share? Not just Visual Studio files, but my game's assets and other files?
Or is this even an option? Am I looking at the wrong service here?

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the repository which contain the files you want to share in one project and import this repository in another project.
The document about cloning repo:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio

The document about importing repo:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops